# Reload Chrome extension tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-tab

Is there some way to get the tab id's of only the tabs that are part of my extension?

Comment: What do you mean "part of my extension"? You could just keep track of tabs your extension creates as you create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on what you mean by "part of my extension".

If you mean tabs that are displaying a page that is contained within your extension you can do the following;

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
  var myTabs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    if (tabs[i].url.indexOf(chrome.extension.getURL('')) === 0) {
      myTabs.push(tabs[i].id);
    }
  }
  console.log(myTabs);
});
```

If you want to access the DOM of your tabs instead, it gets even easier;

```
var myTabs = chrome.extension.getViews({type: 'tab'});
```

With access to the DOM you can simply iterate of each view ([DOMWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window)) and refresh each page;

```
for (var i = 0; i < myTabs.length; i++) {
  myTabs[i].location.reload()
}
```

Comment: I would use the `getViews` method because that will eliminate you to include the `tabs` permission.

Answer (score 4):

```
myTabs[i].location.reload()
```

makes error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reload' of undefined
```

but this code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(myTabs[i].id, {code:"document.location.reload(true);"});
```

works. But better to use [correct method](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html):

```
chrome.tabs.reload(myTabs[i].id)
```

Comment: In your answer, you're referring to `myTabs` from the accepted answer. Please note that the answerer (confusingly) uses the same name ( `myTabs` ) for different collections. `myTabs` from `chrome.tabs.query` returns a [Tab type](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab), which does not have a direct reference to the `window` object. Your answer is correct for this case. At the bottom of the other answer, `myTabs` is an array of `window` objects (returned from `chrome.extension.getViews`). The last code snippet is only applicable to the last `myTabs` object.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do the same thing and using *chrome.tabs.query* and *chrome.tabs.get* didn't work for me. This worked perfectly:

```
var data = chrome.extension.getViews({'type':'tab'});
$.each(data, function(k,v) {
    v.window.location.reload();
});
```